# ASPxScheduler: how to disable Popup Menu for specific appointments?

Tags: devexpress

I am using DevExpress v 10.2. I have a ASP.NET application with an ASPxScheduler control instance. I have customized    pop-up menu (one that appears after right click on an appointment) - the way it is shown in http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument4655.

The problem is: I need to shown the Popup Menu only for specific appointments; and to not show it at all for other appointments (variant: to show it with all menu items disabled for the other appointments).

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
xxx_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    popupMenu1.ShowPopup(Control.MousePosition);
}
```